# How do I display returned JSON from RESTful API call with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, rest, dom, unobtrusive-javascript

After parsing a JSON object, how do I display the returned data from a RESTful API call with vanilla JavaScript?

Do I create HTML elements with the data and add them to the page or do I have hidden HTML elements and innerHTML the returned data then display the elements via CSS?

Comment: That's completely up to you - it's a design choice. Once you have the data you need in a javascript object, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks Nick, but what do you think is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Could you give more insight as to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is, what is the best practice and most performant way to manipulate the DOM and inject html elements with the parsed JSON data.  I have two approaches to this thus far, but the code just seems wrong.  [Version 1](https://github.com/studio174/comp-2112/blob/1.3.0/js/main.js#L48-L93) [Version 2](https://github.com/studio174/comp-2112/blob/1.3.0/js/main2.js#L49-L119) Sorry, I'm fairly new to javascript

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tag you @NickZuber

Comment: If you don't have a huge list, use a table.

Comment: @Knu A table?  As in an HTML table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided the best approach for what I needed was to create an HTML template at the bottom of my html.  This way I could reduce the number of DOM elements I would have to manually code:

```
<script id="daily-template" type="text/template">
    <div class="xl-12">
        <h2 class="location"><?php echo $daily['name']; ?>, <?php echo $daily['sys']['country']; ?></h2>
        <img class="flag" />
    </div>
    <div class="xl-2 s-12 m-6 no-padding-top h140 text-center">
        <h3 class="description"></h3>
        <img class="icon" />
    </div>
    <div class="xl-2 s-12 m-6 no-padding-top h140 text-center">
        <h5>Current</h5>
        <h5 class="temp"></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="xl-2 s-6 m-3 text-center">
        <h5>Low</h5>
        <h5 class="min-temp"></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="xl-2 s-6 m-3 text-center">
        <h5>High</h5>
        <h5 class="max-temp"></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="xl-2 s-6 m-3 text-center">
        <h5>Humidity</h5>
        <h5 class="humidity"></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="xl-2 s-6 m-3 text-center">
        <h5>Wind</h5>
        <h5 class="wind"></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</script>
```

Then using some creative Javascript I:

1. cache the template,
2. create a DOM element to inject the template
3. insert the data
4. and then append the template to the DOM

---

```
/**
 * Display the results from API call
 */

// get the template
var dailyTemplate = document.getElementById('daily-template').innerHTML,
    // create an element to inject the template
    dailySite = document.createElement('div');

// inject the template
dailySite.innerHTML = dailyTemplate;

/** 
 * Inject the data to the template
 */

// location  
dailySite.getElementsByClassName('location')[0].innerHTML = current.name + ', ' + current.sys.country;

// flag
dailySite.getElementsByClassName('flag')[0].src = 'http://openweathermap.org/images/flags/' + current.sys.country.toLowerCase() + '.png';

// description 
dailySite.getElementsByClassName('description')[0].innerHTML = ucfirst(current.weather[0].description);

// weather icon
dailySite.getElementsByClassName('icon')[0].src = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + current.weather[0].icon + '.png';

// all other code omitted...

// append the template to the DOM
document.getElementById("search-results").appendChild(dailySite);
```